# how to use github like cloud sharing

Tags: github, repository

I am pretty new to github and I really liked it.
Now I created a repository. Suppose someone else forked my repository.
Now suppose if I commit some changes in my repository then I want that these changes should also go to that guys repository who forked my repository. But I don't want to make a pull request to the other guys repository every time I make some commit in my repsitory.

Comment: From what I know of git, you can't. The other guy should explicitly ping (via `merge` or `pull`) your branch for your changes to be reflected in his.

Comment: I think the question you are trying to ask is, "how do those who have forked from my repo stay in sync with my subsequent changes?"

Comment: Are you collaborating on the work together?   As there are ways to grant write access to a repository https://help.github.com/articles/how-do-i-add-a-collaborator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has already been commented, for your situation it might be best to just both work on the same repo, without forking. You can do this by having one user create a repo, then they can add a
[**collaborator**](https://help.github.com/en/articles/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository)

- visit the repository's page
- click the settings button

[image: settings]

- click the collaborators tab

[collab http://github-images.s3.amazonaws.com/help/repo-settings-collaborators.png](http://github-images.s3.amazonaws.com/help/repo-settings-collaborators.png)

- enter part of the user's login or email
- select the user from the dropdown
- click add

Once this is all done you can create a local copy by cloning

```
git clone git@github.com:stedolan/jq.git
```

Comment: ok. I added the other guy as a collaborator. Now what the other guy has to do to create a local copy of my repository.?